# Getting "Invalid verification code." on password reset

Tags: error-message, password, hash

I've had a few users on our site have trouble resetting their password. They go through our "Forget password" flow on the front-end of our site, receive the reset email, which allows them to create a new password. But when they try sign in, they receive the following error:

[image]

Based on [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21352/invalid-verification-code-please-login-or-reset-your-password), I thought the issue might have been our email parsing… but here's the weird thing… same thing happens when I grab the reset link directly from the control panel using this dialog then pasting it directly in a different (signed-out) browser:

[image]

I'm getting the exact same error every time I try it with either method (this was definitely working a few months ago on the same server, PHP version, etc).  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In both cases, are you getting that error when you click on the link in the email or when you try to actually login to the Control Panel?

Comment: In both cases, the link works and I can successfully enter a new password… it then redirects me to my front-end sign-in form as expected.

The error displays when I then try to sign in using that front-end sign-in form.

Comment: Okay… weird update:

If I navigate away from the sign-in form, then come back directly using the naked sign-in url, I can successfully sign in with the new password. So it's ONLY after I reset the password, get auto-redirected to my sign-in page, then attempt to sign in.

Also, this seems to only occur with users who don't have control panel access.

Comment: Yeah... not much of that makes sense. :)  If this is on a public box and you want to send some CP/SSH or FTP credentials over to support@craftcms.com, we can poke around a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone makes the same silly mistake I did, I had a conditional on the sign-in page that redirected folks to the page they were on before signing in.

After a password reset, it was trying to redirect back to the Set Password screen with the reset token, resulting in the error.

I just adjusted the conditional so it ignored the referrer URL if it was a control panel action. Problem solved.